# Proportion of variance unexplained by one variable but explained by another variable

Tags: regression, r-squared, partial-correlation

Suppose you have an dependent variable $ Y $ and two dependent variables $ X_2 $ and $X_3$. You want to know the proportion of variance unexplained by $ X_2 $, but explained by $X_3$. How will you find this out? Some ideas that I have are:

- Regress $ Y $ on $ X_2 $ -- take the residuals from this and call it $ \text{YX2Residuals} $ (Regression 1)
- Regress $ Y $ on $ X_3 $ -- take the residuals from this and call it $\text{YX3Residuals} $ (Regression 2)
- Regress $ \text{YX2Residuals}$ on $\text{YX3Residuals}$. (Regression 3)
- The $R^2$ of the last regression gives us the required proportion.

This answer makes the most mathematical sense, because the $R^2$ of the latest regression happens to be the square of the partial correlation coefficient between $ Y $ and  $X3$

However, why should we perform regression (3)? Can't we regres $ \text{YX2Residuals} $ on $ X3 $ and claim that this is the proportion of variance unexplained by $ X2 $ but explained by $X3$? Why should we "net out" $X3$ from $X2$?

Finally, is the answer to this question simply the incremental $R^2$ from adding the $X_3$ to the regression? As in:

- Regress $Y$ on $X_2$ (4)
- Regress $Y$ on $X_2$ and $X_3$ (5)

The proportion of variance unexplained by $X_2$ but explained by $X_3$ is simply the difference between the $R^2$ of (5) and $R^2$ of (4).

Which one of these ideas is correct and why?